# Explanation to this zpool

Tags: zfs

I found such a pool and am asking how the data lays on the disks

```
        NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    ssdpool                      ONLINE       0     5     0
      mirror-0                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50028F820A3d0s7  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c0t5000C50028F81673d0s7  ONLINE       0     0     0
      c0t5000C5001362B05Bd0      ONLINE       0     0     0
    logs
      c1t0d0                     ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      c1t1d0                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      c1t2d0                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      c1t3d0                     ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I am not quite sure if this setup makes really sense. There is a mirror between those slices but then there is a disk attached which is striped?

How would I be able to remove c0t5000C5001362B05Bd0 from this pool without data loss? The existing data fits on the mirror

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks the `ssdpool` is a stripe between a pair of mirrored disk slices and a single disk. You won't be able to shrink the pool or remove that single SSD (c0t5000C5001362B05Bd0). You could, however, add another SSD and mirror that with the existing SSD to add redundancy to the pool. Right now, losing that SSD will cause the pool to fail.

Can we see the full `zpool` listing?

Comment: That is what I thought as well. I have moved the data to a temporary pool and recreated the whole pool. Everything works now. Just wondering why the customer chose to do such a pool :)

Comment: @Chris, wild guess, but it looks like they aren't very sure of what they're doing. Having a couple SSDs in a mirror with (what appears to be) a normal disk for ZIL, and 3 normal disks of L2Arc doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Actually cache and log devices are SSD the other are normal SATA disks. But agree